# SWF posting image file to ASPX page

Tags: c#, apache-flex, flash, axshockwaveflash

I'm trying to save a file using HTTP request from a SWF file to an ASPX file.
i have a WinForms app that hosts the SWF using AxShockwaveFlash control that passes parameters to the SWF that generats the file and posts it to an ASPX page. the page uses the binary data to save the binary stream to a file in the following way:

```
using (Stream stream = Request.InputStream)
        {
            SaveStreamToFile("C:\\Curves\\" + System.ToString() + "_" + Instrument.ToString() + ".jpg", stream);
        }
```

when running the SWF from the development enviroment the ASPX saves the file, but when running from the app it doesn't. anybody?

Comment: Are the app and SWF location on the same domain?

Comment: yes. the app is hosting the file using axshockwaveflash .

Comment: Does the app have permission to write the file? Does the SWF have the post url hard-coded?

Answer (score 0):

Just for being on the safe side , try using the cross-domain.xml file on the server.That makes a difference sometimes.

Comment: no.checked it on wireshark- no approach for cross-domain file.